# Custom BaseEntity in Entity Framework Model-First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with the Entity Framework Model-First and I want to implement a `BaseEntity` for each entity in the edmx. I cannot find a working solution anywhere. Can anyone help me with this?

This is what the `BaseEntity` looks like:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I want each entity in my datamodel to have these properties for administrative purposes. The `BaseEntity` is defined outside the edmx because I cannot Ignore it in the `OnModelCreating` because I am using Model-First.

I know I can specify `Inheritance` for each `Entity` by hand in the designer but this will be a lot of work and my design will not remain very flexible

Comment: You should be able to right click on your entity, select properties and set the base type.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I know. Forgot to mention. Please see my edit

Comment: Ah OK, in that case, you probably have to edit the T4 template

Comment: @DavidG I have tried that as well (https://fairwaytech.com/2013/09/using-a-common-base-class-across-entity-framework-database-first-entities/). This adds the inheritance to the generated classes, but not to the model itself (and the generated SQL)

Comment: What is the difference? The model is the class.

Comment: @DavidG Yes you're right. I don't know how to put it.. After changing the template, how can I force the code generation to run again to implement the inheritance?

Comment: Been a while since I did DB first, but you can either do it from the EDMX or right click the T4 template and select one of the options on there.

Comment: @DavidG I cannot find any suitable option right there. I'll try to convince my colleagues to move to Code-First because what I want to achieve, doens;t seem to be possible in Model-First. Thank you for your help